# Activating the hover state of a button when it's clicked until another button is clicked (Javascript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am currently creating a website for my freelance work and am using the click() and load() functions provided by JQuery. Everything works great, I added the hover effect through classname:hover in css as always.

What I want to do now is make a clicked button stay in the hover effect as long as another button gets clicked. I saw several posts about the add function, but could just not make it work. I hope someone here is able and willing to help me!

Here are my codes:

HTML

```
<div class="button" id="buttonHome">HOME</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonHome').click(function(){
            $("#content").load("includes/sample.html");
            $('button').addClass('hover');
        });
    })
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    width: auto;
    height: 22px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
} .button:hover, .button.hover{border-bottom: thin solid #ffffff;color: #c4c4c4;}
```

If anything else is needed, just tell me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the buttons are

```
<div class="button">HOME</div>
<div class="button">ABOUT</div>
<div class="button">Contact</div>
```

Now the script part

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $('.button').click(function() {
       $('.button').removeClass('active');
       var el = $(this);
       el.addClass('active');
    })


  })
</script>
```

Now the css part

```
<style>
  .active {
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element is a `<div>`, not a `<button>`, though it has the class button, so I think you mean:

```
$(".button").addClass("hover");
```

---

In jQuery, you target an element with the same selector you use in CSS, so `$("button")` targets `<button>` elements, while `$(".button")` targets any element with the button class.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xurwmms/)

Comment: I already tried this and didn't get it to work as I wanted it. 
Currently I am running with this code:

`$(function(){
        $("#buttonHome").bind("click", function(){
                if($("#buttonHome").attr("hover") == "on"){
                        
                }else{
                    $("#buttonHome").attr("hover", "on");
                    $("#content").load("includes/sample.html");
                }
        });
    });`